# Trying to make a visit counter + IP unique in CBV for django blog

Tags: django

I'm doing an integer field in models fou counting the visits, but I would like to be filtered also by IP.

```
counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Post
    template_name = 'article_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"]= cat_menu
        return context

    def get_client_ip(request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        return ip
```

I'm not sure how to do the logic in CBV for the count. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to do some database operation (increment the counter) in the end of every request. For DetailView, you can do this by overriding `get` method:

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # add counter logic here, for example
        self.object.counter = django.db.models.F('counter') + 1
        self.object.save()
        return response
```